# How to connect to specific Schema in H2

Tags: java, h2

So I have created a few schema in H2.
How can I connect to a specific schema in H2

For example when I need to connect to a specific schema in SQL Server I have below JDBC URL

```
jdbc:sqlserver://HOSTNAME:PORT;SelectMethod=cursor;instanceName=MYSCHEMA;databaseName=DBNAME
```

Is this feature available in H2.
If not is there a workaround.

I do not want to always access a particular table in my schema instance be accessed like `MYSCHEMA.TABLE_NAME`

Otherwise I suppose only way out will be to create all table into the default schema that is public

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is such feature supported. See this:

http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_schema

You can specify the schema in the connection string:

```
jdbc:h2:test;SCHEMA=SCHEMA_NAME
```

You can also change the current schema with:

```
SET SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: not quiet correct. Set schema works when you are executing a query. It will also work if you are executing a script file. But in this case my question is more towards setting up schema for JDBC connection. As you may know setting up schema for the execution allows us to access tables without schema name.

Comment: @Acewin Did you actually checked the link? You can set which schema you want to use while connecting to database. Use format jdbc:h2:test;SCHEMA=ABC for your connection URL.

Comment: Thanks. You should really put the format 'jdbc:h2:test;SCHEMA=ABC' in your answer instead of in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Fixed the problem for me. Kudos

Answer (score 3):

```
SET SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH shemaName
```

http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html?highlight=drop%2Calias&search=drop%20alias#set_schema_search_path

Comment: good info. In case querying multiple schemas at the same time. Otherwise it takes the default schema

Answer (score 0):

You can also supply a *schema* property in the *info* parameter of

```
java.​sql.​DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info).
```